# stm32 development on 23.04

Tags: eclipse

Trying to start development for stm32 boards but struggling to install stm32cubeide. The first version relies on libpython2.7. Using the vanilla version en.st-stm32cubeide_1.12.1_16088_20230420_1057_amd64.sh.zip fails because of issue with libswt-gtk-4950r5.so+0x3ed16

The VS Code Stm32 extension requires stm32cubeide (.cproject) to import project and does not support importing of stm32cubeMX projects (.ioc)

I can use CMake or nakefiles but wondered if people knew of a better approach. Maybe a conversation tool.

Thanks

Comment: Answered in https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00002IMDFZSA5/import-project-in-vs-code-ubuntu-2404